# Darius autem cum ex Europa in Asiam redisset

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, cornelius-nepos

This is from Nepos on Miltiades.

Darius autem cum ex Europa in Asiam redisset

The translator put this as:

Darius, when he had returned from Asia into Europe

But I would think it would be:

Darius, when he had returned from Europe into Asia.

Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Translation by John Selby Watson (London: George Bell and Sons, 1886). http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ENG1360/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say why Watson translated it that way. The Latin is unambiguous. Indeed, it's "from Europe (*ex Europa*) (in)to Asia (*in Asiam*). I checked the Budé edition, and there's no note indicating an alternative reading from the manuscripts.

I'd probably just chalk it up to a mistake, although he might have been "correcting" the text, since immediately after this Persians are back in Greece to capture Eretria. It is possible he misunderstood the sequence of the action.

Then again, it might just be a typo, too, as just a little bit above you see the following typo: "Miltiades, in consequence, exhorted the guardians of the bridge not to lose an opportunity, presented them **by by** fortune."

Comment: Possibly another case of [temporary insanity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Selby_Watson) on the part of the Reverend John Selby Watson 

Comment: I blame the type setter or the person who transferred the text onto the internet.